# Min and max of $x^2+xy$ when $x^2+3y^2 = 9$

Tags: inequality

What is the minimum and maximum of $x^2+xy$ when $x^2+3y^2 = 9$?

I tried to make the expression $x^2+xy$ all in terms of $x$ but it is not going well after that.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Put $x=3 \cos t,\ y=\sqrt{3}\sin t,$ then for $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ the pair $(x,y)$ goes through all solutions of $x^2+3y^2=9.$ So now insert these values of $x,y$ into the objective function $x^2+xy$ to get a function of one variable $t$ which may be minimized and maximized in the usual one-variable calculus way. This gives the values of $t$ to go back and find $x,y$ which make the max and min.

Comment: What methods do you know to compute extremal values subject to constraints?

Comment: Solve for one variable in the second one and plug into first one, take a derivative set equal to zero and plug back in to find other value and plug both into first equation. So $x=\sqrt{9-3y^2}$ so find $f’$ when $f=9-3y^2+y\sqrt{9-3y^2}$ and set $f’=0$.

Comment: I've compiled my comment into a simple solution, see below.

Comment: For comparison with other results, here are wolframs max and min: max approx 9.696 at (x,y)=+/-(2.89,0.44) and min approx -0.696 at (x,y)=+/-(0.776,-1.67)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=extrema+x%5E2%2Bxy+subject+to+x%5E2%2B3y%5E2%3D9

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that you think it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

**HINT** -
Try to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier(Lagrange multiplier), and you'll get that if
$\begin{align}
L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)-\lambda(x^2+3y^2-9)\end{align}$, then you know that the min and max points are when the derivative=0, so: $\begin{align}L^{'}(x,y,z)_x&=2x+y-2\lambda x=0\\
L^{'}(x,y,\lambda)_y&=x-6\lambda y=0\\
L^{'}(x,y,\lambda)_\lambda&=-x^2+3y^2+9=0
\end{align}$
From here you should just solve for $(x,y)$ and see which ones are the min and max.

---

Other way would be to say that $x=\pm\sqrt{9-3y^2}$, substitue it into $x^2+xy$ and from here you can seek for the min and max points like in highschool